# when does css render?

Tags: css, rendering, document-ready

I was thinking of using a css transition with a delay as sort of a small animated intro for a page the other day.  Is css rendered immediately after its loaded (before the document if fully loaded/ready)? If so I suppose I could add the `<link>` tag after the document is ready for a similar effect.

Comment: Once stylesheets are downloaded, their styles are applied immediately as the DOM builds. Not sure what happens with transitions though.

Answer (score 0):

On http://www.chapmansbuilding.co.uk/, I added a big white div with JS over the whole content, then did the animation, then removed the div. This meant that I could ensure the remaining content was rendered and preloaded etc at the same time.

Make sure you add it with JS, else the site won't be visible for a user without JS, or if your JS script fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the specs and other docs, the transitions are applied immediately when a computed value changes:

> When the computed value of an
>   animatable property changes,
>   implementations must decide what
>   transitions to start based on the
>   values of the ‘transition-property’,
>   ‘transition-duration’,
>   ‘transition-timing-function’, and
>   ‘transition-delay’ properties at the
>   time the animatable property would
>   first have its new computed value.

[From here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/)

So this happens with `hover` or `focus` or some other event.

If you wanted your transition to run on page load, you would need to use some javascript as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions#Using_transition_events_to_animate_an_object

If you were worried about the transition happening too quickly, you could set a delay in the js.